# Force command-line tool to use different interface?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing, tcpip

I have a service which I want to run over eth1.
But all my other traffic still needs to run over eth0.

Is it possible to force a command-line tool or other application to use the non default interface?

Comment: If you need different programs to use different routes to the same IP address, you need to use packet mangling. See [multigateway routing for specific src port](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1194/885), [Dual network connection](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4242/885), [2 network interfaces connected to internet. Choose the one to use according to the domain name](http://askubuntu.com/q/4988/1059) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark, but does the service allow you to bind to specific IP addresses?  If eth1 has its own IP address (i.e. not bonded with eth0) this may do what you want.  Outside of that, you may be able to have it access an external IP address that's only routed over eth1.

Comment: Ive looked and no it doesnt have options to route it over a different interface. Im messing with hellanzb, ive looked through the documentation and the config file and i didnt see anyplace to specify the interface.

Comment: @madmaze - the routing wouldn't be an option in the app itself, but you'd set up a route from your machine to the server specifically over the eth1 interface.  This would make all traffic to the server use eth1, which may not be what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can probably configure the application to bind to the ip address you have configured on eth1. If, however, your default route goes out eth0, your outbound traffic, while tagged with the IP on eth1, will likely still leave the host on eth1.

Comment: Binding to a particular IP address will make the application respond only to connection requests that arrive on a particular interface. But if there are multiple routes to the same IP address, this won't affect which one is taken.