# Forcing two instances of a Java Application to use different network interfaces on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, 64-bit, java, network-adapter

As the title says I am looking for some method of having two instances of the same Java application (that lack this type of setting) to access the internet using different adapters.

I found a [couple](https://superuser.com/questions/181882/force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-interface) [of](https://superuser.com/questions/960496/how-to-make-different-applications-use-a-different-network-interface) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes) [regarding](https://superuser.com/questions/753935/same-web-service-running-on-different-network-interface) [the](https://superuser.com/questions/224339/force-command-line-tool-to-use-different-interface) topic, here, but only for other OSs.

Although being off-topic, a guy proposed [a windows solution](https://superuser.com/questions/181882/force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-interface/682153#682153) on a OS X question to ForceBindIp, speaking of which I had finally found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1004697/bind-application-to-a-specific-network-interface) but neither the accepted answer  nor the "let's abuse HideMyAss' Secure IP Bind" one satisfied me because they apparently don't work on 64-bit processes.

My system is x64-based so are many processes, including the JVM, are 64-bit processes, thus unsuitable for the dll injection performed by the proposed programs.

Comment: This seems more like a Stackoverflow question, but for that to be well received, you must at least attempt to do it yourself.  How you would do that is break the question down to the simplest form, "Force Java application to use a specific network adapter", research that topic then attempt to do that and post the code on SO.

Comment: @Ramhound This question is posed by me, the user of a Java Application that has no setting for adapter binding. AFAIK this is a SuperUser question: there is no programming involved, so I have no code to show. I'm just attempting to run two instances of a third-party Java application on two different network interfaces. I'm looking for a different tool from the ones i found, because of the x64 JVM.

Comment: How was I suppose to know all that?

Comment: @Ramhound I just repeated what's in the question... Regarding the non-programming part I suppose you have already read [this page describing what is on topic and what is not on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic): I would have asked it on SO if it was a programming question. I welcome any attempt at improving the question from you, if you believe that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ForceBindIP? It was updated recently and supports 64 bit apps and Windows 10. Make sure you get it from the official site at https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip as other sites may be hosting old versions.

Comment: I'm checking it out! Thanks for pointing out that it was updated. Does it support forcing child processes spawned by the target process?